# Intelligent resizing background

Tags: javascript, html, css

Excuse me for this, probably spoony, question. But when skinning controls/elements I'm usually using the following concept (I don't know the correct name, but I first saw it when creating custom WinXP themes). The basic idea is to set up a sort of margins in the image that restrict resizing, only the inner parts are allowed to stretch.

http://img42.imageshack.us/img42/6188/image7rq.jpg

When using this method in my regular programming work life is easy, I just `BitBlt` the four corner and then `StretchBlt` the remaining parts into place. However I'm no expert on HTML and I cannot find anything on the internet about it. It's kinda difficult to search when you don't exactly know the name of the concept...

a) How is this method called?

b) Does anyone know how to do this using HTML, CSS, Javascript, etc.? Preferably I would like the background of a `DIV` element to be themed like this. It's the intention to not spend the rest of this day slicing images in Photoshop ok, that makes me feel so utterly miserable..

Comment: You can user `border-radius` to round corners.  Here is a nifty tool that will help you generate the css: http://css3generator.com/

Comment: That link is very useful, added to my favs thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's several ways to approach this.  If you are allowed to target newer browsers and allow old browsers to degrade to square corners and non-gradient backgrounds, check out the [new CSS 3 features](http://www.zetalight.com/css3-shadow-rounded-corners-gradient-cross-browser-css3-support/).

If, however, you need to be able to support old browsers, you're going to have to fire up Photoshop, create some background images, and nest some html elements.  If your background only has to scale in one direction (verically or horizontally) check out the [sliding door](http://azadcreative.com/2009/03/bulletproof-css-sliding-doors/) technique.

Comment: User having an old browser seeing squared images, I don't mind, go update your browser I would say! Thanks, I'll do it with CSS3.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't be easier to use css instead? Check thishttp://jonraasch.com/blog/css-rounded-corners-in-all-browsers or do a search for 'css rounded box' or 'css rounded corners'